# How to get the OAuth code from the redirect URI displayed in the browser using Django URLs

Tags: python, django, oauth, docusignapi

I am integrating Django app with the Docusign API, for the authorization I am using OAuth2 grant_type="code", after passing all the required params to the /oauth/auth (`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=33f*******NNNNMNMc-b478-7593294fb3ba&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/sales/oauth/callback`) endpoint I am getting the Oauth code in the browser to the redirect URI(http://localhost:3000/sales/oauth/callback), I want to fetch this code from my django class view where I have created a path to my view as

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "sales/oauth/callback",
        OAuthCallbackView.as_view(),
        name="OAuthCallbackView",
    ),
]
```

and my view

```
class OAuthCallbackView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        access_code = request.GET["code"]
```

I want to get the auth code here, since the redirect URI path contains the code (/sales/oauth/callback?code=12312232) I am not able to hit the URL path mentioned above

Is there a way I can get the Oauth code in Django

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code,  we'll have this code (find in [GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/sample-app-myhealthcare-python/blob/master/frontend/src/api/auth.js) too)

```
def callback(request):
    """
    The final part of the user authorization using the OAuth
    """
    serializer = CallbackSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    code = serializer.validated_data['code']

    try:
        auth_data = DsClient.callback(code)
    except ApiException:
        return redirect("jwt_auth")

    SessionData.set_auth_data(request.session, auth_data)
    return Response({"message": "Logged in with code grant"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't find the answer for my query. My requirement was to hit the Django view with redirect URI (path mentioned above). This above code seems to be calling the function directly when we hit the URL.

Comment: Well, not sure why that doesn't work, I don't know how to hit the view with the redirect URI

Comment: I am having the same question, somehow when I refresh the page which contains the `code` it works, this means auto-refreshing the code once should solve the problem

Comment: Aditya, are you using Django?